# How to let Glide check the cached file on disk at provided path?

Tags: java, android, caching, android-glide

We know that Glide first checks memory cache, then disk cache and then in the end downloads file if it can't find it.

My aim is to "tell" Glide, when it needs file from disk, where to find it and if it does not exist there, download and save it at that path.

The reason I want this is to ensure that I can make use of that downloaded file again anywhere else in my app if I need. That way, if file has already been downloaded by some part of the app, Glide will not download it again and use it straight away. Otherwise, Glide it will download it and someone else will not have to download it again and use it.

Is it possible to tell Glide to look for and download (if needed) file at the path that we as a developer provide?

Any suggestions as to how to achieve it?